# 404 Not Found or Bad Request?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404, asp.net-web-api2, api-design

Let's say that we have the following REST call:

```
GET api/companies/5
```

*(get company with id 5)*

If company '5' doesn't exist, we would typically return a `404 Not Found` response.

But now, let's take this call:

```
GET api/companies/5/invoices/10
```

*(get invoice 10 from company 5)*

Now, if company '5' doesn't exist, do we still return a `404 Not Found`?  Or should a 404 only be returned if the outer most resource can not be found (invoice 10, in this case).

Would `Bad Request` perhaps be a better option?

Comment: the best would be to have a 404 but handled with a custom error message, its always better to hide ugly errors to users

Comment: technically speaking, it should be 404. But response body may contain anything. Full response will drive the next step.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

404 is your best response.  According to the HTTP RFC, http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt,

A 400 Bad Request means:

> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.

Whereas, 404 states:

> The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI.

The entire URI is your resource identifier, and you're not finding a matching resource for that particular identifier.

Answer (score 6):

404 may cause a confusion - is the resource missing or is the actual URL incorrect?

I'd personally go for the `422` code:

```
   The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
   understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
   415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
   syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request)
   status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
   instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
   request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
   semantically erroneous, XML instructions.
```