# Spring MVC Controller URL not mapped

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to make simple project in Spring MVC,but getting this error :

WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCForm/login.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springform'

HTTP Status 404 - Not Found.

Not able to get what I am missing. Please let me know.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>SpringMVCForm</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>

    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springform</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springform</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

springform-servlet.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.mvcform.*" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

LoginController.java

```
package com.mvcform.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login.htm")
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView processCredentials(@RequestParam("userId") String userId, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
        String message = "Invalid Credentials";
        if (userId != null && userId.length() >= 5) {
            if (userId.equals(password)) {
                //message = "Welcome " + userId + " !!!";
                return new ModelAndView("redirect:/showform");
            }
        }
        return new ModelAndView("index", "message", message);
    }
}
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring MVC Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1> Index.jsp </h1>

<h1>Enter your user id and password</h1>
    <form action="login.htm" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td> User Id </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="userId" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password </td>
                <td> <input type="password" name="password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I think Spring is not able to scan base package: com.mvcform.*

Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: can you try to write <context:component-scan base-package="com.mvcform" /> ? (the .* is too much, it ask for a package here)

Comment: i tried this as well but still not working

Comment: When are you getting error, after submit form?

Comment: yes after submit form

Answer (score 0):

1) if you  configured correct then you must check the json format which you sending to server to save it may be wrong (refere the url[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26968479/404-not-found-or-bad-request))

2) please check your controller controller doesn't have this url "**URI [/SpringMVCForm/login.htm]**"  you have only **/login.htm** url.

Comment: SpringMVCForm is name of my project, do I need to write that also in my RequestMapping

Comment: not require in RequestMapping but you must use project name while hitting any url or making any url call.

Answer (score 0):

Remove 
@RequestMapping("/login.htm")

and keep only
@RequestMapping("/login")

in controller